How do we correctly express the volume charge density over a flat disc with radius $R$ using spherical coordinates?
Using Dirac delta functions in the appropriate coordinates, express the following charge distributions as 3-dimensional charge densities $\rho(\vec{x})$.
a) In spherical coordinates a charge $Q$ spread uniformly over a flat circular disc of negligible thickness radius $R$.
Here is my attempt on the solution:
$$
\rho(\vec{x}) = A \left[ H(R-r) \right]\delta\left( \theta - \frac{\pi}{2} \right)
$$
$$
Q = \iiint \rho(x) \, dx = \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty A \left[ H(R-r) \right] \delta\left( \theta - \frac{\pi}{2} \right) (r^2 \sin\theta \, dr \, d\theta \, d\phi)
$$
$$
= A \left[ \int_0^\pi \delta\left( \theta - \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \sin\theta \, d\theta \right] \left[ \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \right] \left[ \int_0^\infty \left[ H(R-r) \right] r^2 \, dr \right]
$$
$$
= A \left( \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \right) (2\pi) \left[ \int_0^R r^2 \, dr + \int_R^\infty 0 \times r^2 \, dr \right]
$$
$$
= A(1)(2\pi) \left( \frac{R^3}{3} \right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
A = \frac{3Q}{2\pi R^3},
$$
and the charge density is
$$
\rho(x) = \frac{3Q}{2\pi R^3} \left[ H(R-r) \right] \delta\left( \theta - \frac{\pi}{2} \right).
$$
My problem is that in expressing $\rho$. Some solutions say that I have to put $\frac{1}{r}$ in the expression, but I have trouble understanding why. They say that $\rho$ have $r$-dependence, but didn't the question imply that the charge density distribution is uniform?

In cylindrical coordinates, the charge density should be
$$ \rho(s, \theta, z) = \frac{Q}{\pi R^2} H(R - s) \delta(z) $$
where $H$ is the Heaviside step function and $s$ is the radial coordinate. When we transform this into spherical roodinates, using $z = r \cos \varphi$  the delta function becomes $\delta(r \cos \varphi)$. Then we can use the formula
$$ \delta(f(x)) = \sum_{f(x_i) = 0} \frac{\delta(x - x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}$$
We can ignore the point $r = 0$ since it's just a single point. So basically $r \cos \varphi = 0$ when $\varphi = \pi/2$, and the above formula then becomes
$$ \delta(r \cos \varphi) = \frac{\delta(\varphi - \pi/2)}{r}$$
so the charge density in spherical coordinates is
$$\rho(r, \theta, \varphi) = \frac{Q}{\pi R^2} \frac{1}{r} H(R - r) \delta(\varphi - \pi/2) $$
In this derivation, the factor of $1/r$ came from dividing from the derivative of $r \cos \varphi$, but it can also be motivated by physical intuition. Think of the delta function as having width $\mathrm{d}x$ and height $\mathrm{d}x^{-1}$, where $\mathrm{d}x$, the thickness of the disk, is very small. Then $\delta(\varphi - \pi/2)$ would be equal to $\mathrm{d}x^{-1}$ on the slice $\varphi \in [-\mathrm{d}x/2, \mathrm{d}x/2]$. But the bigger $r$ is, the more space that slice takes up in Cartesian coordinates: it basically becomes $z \in [-r\, \mathrm{d}x/2, r\, \mathrm{d}x/2]$. If the slice is thicker by a factor of $r$ then we have to introduce a compensating factor of $1/r$ to the density.
